# Implementing own function in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I am implementing my own function for calculating taxes. Below you can see the data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"id_n":["1","2","3","4","5"],
                               "sales1":[0,115000,440000,500000,740000],
                               "sales2":[0,115000,460000,520000,760000],
                               "tax":[0,8050,57500,69500,69500]
                  })
```

[image]

Now I want to introduce a tax function that needs to give the same results as results in column tax. Below you can see an estimation of that function:

```
            # Thresholds
        min_threeshold = 500000
        max_threeshold = 1020000
            
            # Maximum taxes
        max_cap = 69500
            
            # Rates
        rate_1 = 0.035
        rate_2 = 0.1 
            
            # Total sales
        total_sale = df['sales1'] + df['sales2']
        tax = df['tax']
    
    # Function for estimation
    def tax_fun(total_sale,tax,min_threeshold,max_threeshold,max_cap,rate_1,rate_2):
        if (total_sale > 0 and tax == 0):
           calc_tax = 0
        elif (total_sale < min_threeshold): 
           calc_tax = total_sale * rate_1  
        elif (total_sale >= min_threeshold) &  (total_sale <= max_threeshold): 
           calc_tax =  total_sale * rate_2 
        elif (total_sale > max_threeshold):
          calc_tax = max_cap  
        return calc_tax
```

So far so good. The next step is the execution of the above function. Below you can see the command :

```
df['new_tax']=tax_fun(total_sale,tax,min_threeshold,max_threeshold,max_cap,rate_1,rate_2)
```

After execution of this command, I received this error

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

So can anybody help me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use df.apply(), you're almost there!

```
def someFunc():
     # do something here
     return result

def main():
    # setup df
    new_col = 'col_name'
    df[new_col] = df.apply(lambda x: someFunc(x['some_col']))
```

This is powerful because within x you now have access to each row, so you can pass data from the row to your custom function and then apply it - using optimized pandas - to each row.

I forget the object structure for x, so you may want to look into that and you can access what you need. Also, x can be named anything.

Docs here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the hint. But this does not solve my problem. I need to have these results only with one function, not with a nested function and apply

Comment: You can replace lambda with an inline function